# Why swap size is 4 KiB less than the underlying device?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I created a zfs volume and enabled swap on it:

```
swapon: /dev/zd0: found swap signature: version 1d, page-size 4, same byte order
swapon: /dev/zd0: pagesize=4096, swapsize=5368709120, devsize=5368709120
```

So as one may see the `devsize` is exactly 5 gigabytes.

`free` command outputs though:

```
Swap:       5242876           0     5242876
```

And 5242876 KiB is 4 KiB less than the device capacity.

Is there a way to make swap exactly 5gb other than giving the device size 4 more mysterious KiB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap filesystem contain some header info see https://askubuntu.com/a/846172/141639 - so if you want 5GB swap you must allocate 4kiB (one page size) more.